# Symfony CMF auto routing bundle

Tags: symfony

I have been trying to use symfony cmf routing auto bundle to make my route dynamic and I have been trying to install this bundle.

If I am correct for implementation of cmf bundle PHPCR is required and implementation of phpcr is to be made with jackalope Doctrine DBAL. I am trying to download the jackalope doctrine DBAL to use phpcr bundle but jackalope is not installed and reverted with error. Please correct me if I am mistaken and if not what is the problem with Jackalope doctrine dbal.

This is my composer.json file

```
{
"name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": "src/", "SymfonyStandard": "app/" }
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.6.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3,<2.5",
    "doctrine/dbal": "<2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
    "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.12",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",
     "jackalope/jackalope-doctrine-dbal":" 1.2.*@dev",
     "phpcr/phpcr-utils": "1.2.*@dev",
    "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "dev-master",
    "symfony-cmf/routing-bundle": "1.4.*@dev",
    "symfony-cmf/routing-auto-bundle": "1.1.*@dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "2.2.*@dev"


},
"require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "SymfonyStandard\\Composer::hookRootPackageInstall"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.6-dev"
    }
}

}
```

When updating `composer.json` following error is shown:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.        

Problem 1                                                                       
  - jackalope/jackalope-doctrine-dbal 1.2.x-dev requires jackalope/jackalop     
e ~1.2.0 -> no matching package found.                                            
   - jackalope/jackalope-doctrine-dbal 1.2.0-RC1 requires doctrine/dbal ~2.5     
,>=2.5.0 -> no matching package found.                                            
 - Installation request for jackalope/jackalope-doctrine-dbal  1.2.*@dev -     
> satisfiable by jackalope/jackalope-doctrine-dbal[1.2.0-RC1, 1.2.x-dev].         

Potential causes:                                                                 
- A typo in the package name                                                     
- The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your      
minimum-stability setting                                                         
see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion     
> for more details.                                                               

Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further     common problems.
```

When accessing my project bundle following error appears:

```
InvalidConfigurationException in CmfRoutingAutoExtension.php line 72:
No adapter has been configured, you either need to enable a persistence   layer        or explicitly specify an adapter using the "adapter" configuration key.
```

What is meant by "no adapter has been configured"?

Answer (score 0):

The error says it doesn't find `jackalope/jackalope` ....

So just install the `jackalope/jackalope` :

**Here is the packagist link :** https://packagist.org/packages/jackalope/jackalope